# How could I know a tag's specific meaning in DICOM?

Tags: dicom, medical

I was doing a project on dicom, and I found the DICOM Standard document(http://medical.nema.org/standard.html) is really a mess for programmers.For example when I come across a Tag(0008, 0060), I look into 11_03pu.pdf(http://medical.nema.org/Dicom/2011/11_03pu.pdf). It is said to be a modality with some value(GM, SM). Where could I find a more specific meaning about the tag and the value (GM, SM...) ?

Answer (score 3):

The index of Part 3 contains a mapping from Tag to page. There you can find any reference to your tag in question. Looking at the referenced pages will show you how the tag is used, what it means in what situation and so on.

Comment: I've found that.It's really kind of you!@A.H.

Answer (score 2):

Well, dicom standard is your friend. But normally, any dicom parser contains what is called a dictionary that maps tag keys (two short numbers) to tag name and type. Without such a dictionary it is not possible to parse dicom data encoded implicitly.

Another thing you can look at is dicom modules (also defined in standard). Modules are groups of tags assembled by some global meaning (e.g. patient data, study data, equipment, image). Then you know for instance that for CR image one must put together patient, study, series, exposure, image plane, etc. modules in order to obtain a valid data set.

I would recommend you [Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642108490) book, before reading dicom standard, this will ease your suffering.

Comment: Thanks @Archie, I'll buy this book and have a look, maybe what I should do first is to calm down:)

Comment: you can read DICOM dataset encoded in little endian without dictionary, otherwise how would you deal with newly added attributes going through an old implementation.

Comment: You can read dicom file in any encoding, but you cannot interpret it without a dictionary if the encoding is implicit, because you do not have value representations (VRs) going with tags. In explicit encoding, VRs are encoded directly, so you can interpret tag data types, but still cannot tell the meaning of them without a dictionary.

Comment: Excellent book, much better than reading the literal standard, a.k.a. DICOMNOMICON ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can also find more information with Dicom PS 3 as well in [Tag Info](http://www.dicomtags.com/iods/search)

Answer (score 0):

List of DICOM Tags are located under chapter 6 of DICOM Standard PS 3.6 or part 6. This list includes DICOM element Name, Tag number, Value Representation (VR) and Value Multiplicity (VM) of the tag value. Also, tag value encoding rules are located under sections 6 of PS 3.5 or part 5. See table 6.2-1.
You can download the DICOM standard from http://medical.nema.org/standard.html